# How to add post meta fields to an article's <head> as meta elements

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, seo, google

I need to add the following type of meta information in the article

```
    <meta name="citation_publication_date" content="1996/05/17">
    <meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Journal of Biological Chemistry">
    <meta name="citation_volume" content="271">
    <meta name="citation_issue" content="20">
    <meta name="citation_firstpage" content="11761">
    <meta name="citation_lastpage" content="11766">
    <meta name="citation_pdf_url"content="http://www.example.com/content/271/20/11761.full.pdf">
```

https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing

Comment: Can you tell us what have you done so far?

Comment: So far i have successfully implemented the title and the author. Since their is not a must for them to be in the form of meta data

Comment: If you are comfortable working with PHP you can use wp_head action hook to add the required meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post edit screen you can add the data as custom fields and then pull those custom fields into your post templates, like this:

[image: Adding custom fields to a post]

If you'd like a better admin interface for these fields, that's possible and there are plenty of guides around the web and on this site.  Search for `admin metabox`.

To pull the data into your theme, add this *untested* code to `functions.php` or if you can't edit the theme make it into your own plugin.

```
function wpse_235005_post_meta(){

    if ( !is_single() ) {
        return; 
        /* bail out if not showing a single post of the right type
           You may want to adjust this conditional to suit your site,
           maybe checking for a custom post type
        */
    }

    global $post; // outside the loop make sure we can see this post

    $fields = array(
        "citation_publication_date",
        "citation_journal_title",
        "citation_volume",
        "citation_issue",
        "citation_firstpage",
        "citation_lastpage",
        "citation_pdf_url"
    )

    foreach( $fields as $field ) {

        if( $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true) ) {

            // in PHP empty strings are falsy

            echo '<meta name="';
            echo $field;
            echo '" content="';
            echo $value;
            echo '">';
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_235005_post_meta');
/* adjust the priority to move your meta elements up or down 
   within your document's head
*/
```